# Git Remote Repository Fetch Hook

Tags: git, bash

I have a bare remote repository and want to invoke a hook when a "git fetch" is performed against it.

I have tried several hooks that I thought might work (post-merge, which I know is for local repos but thought I'd try it anyways), I have also tried replacing some of the git-* binaries (such as git-upload-archive and git-upload-pack) with scripts that then invoke the binaries.

Any ideas on how I can trigger a script to run when a "git fetch" is performed against a remote repository? And yes, I am aware of the docs (http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/githooks/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is that you can't -- the hooks are called after write operations. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks for better wording on the use of the server hooks.

Comment: I was looking at this doc: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols and in the section about SSH connections it mentions running git-upload-pack remotely. I thought if I could replace git-upload-pack that would give me what I need, however when I remove the binary I can still push and pull to and from the remote repo.